# class debug, how to know from where the class was called

Tags: c#, asp.net, debugging

I know that the question may be not very clear, but i have this problem I spend a lot of time trying to solve it but I got nothing, I debug my website, and it seems that after page load event finish, the page calls another classes that I didn't call.

I was hopping if there is a way of debugging that tells me from where the class was called, or who called that class

Comment: Isn't call stack helpful to figure out who has called you class?

Comment: okay I'm new to asp and c# 
how do i call the stack ?

Comment: How do I call the stack? That was funny, in a way. Maybe you are looking for `CallerMemberName` http://bit.ly/1H7dwEi

Comment: @kamalsaeed Loosely speaking, "Call Stack" is a structure containing the methods that have been called up to the break point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the "call stack" to figure out who has called you class. To do so, put a break point in your code (wherever you think is appropriate) and when the application runs into it, check you call stack window (which is at the bottom of your IDE usually, alternatively you can find it here: **Debug** menu -> **Windows** -> **Call Stack** (Ctrl + Alt + C)).

Programmatically, you can print out "Environment.StackTrace" Property. This property (as its name suggest) contains the call stack. You should put it where the code enters you class (i.e. one of the class's methods/accessors).

Comment: okay it worked! 
now I know from where it's called 
I have another question, if you can help me with!

Answer (score 2):

Using the call stack window:
[image]

you can see where your functions have been called by.

This can be accessed by Debug -> Windows -> Call Stack (Ctrl + Alt + C)

(Thank you [Camilo Ward](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4867086/camilo-ward))

Comment: I don't think Call Stack resides in "Windw" menu. Mine does not have it (and yes, I'm in debugging mode and have already ran the application).
@kamal: if you look at the bottom of your IDE when your application is executing, you can find it.

Comment: It's in the Debug -> Windows -> Call Stack (Ctrl + Alt + C)

Comment: Yeah, its always come up for me when I hit a breakpoint or an error has been thrown. MDSN said it was under the window menu.